# How to set relative paths in the node <rosjava-pathelement> included in a manifest.xml for ROSJava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, I have a package running a solution which uses external java libraries. The solution use external libraries, but I would like to use relative path to the package. With this idea, all libraries would be included in lib folder.

Current solution is this one:

```
<export>
    <rosjava-src location="src" /> 
    <rosjava-pathelement location="target/" groupId="org.lejos.ros" artifactId="org.lejos.ros.nodes.NXTLoader" version="0.0.1" built="true" />
    <rosjava-pathelement location="/usr/local/lejos/lib/pc/pccomm.jar" />
    <rosjava-pathelement location="/usr/local/lejos/lib/pc/3rdparty/bluecove-gpl.jar" />
    <rosjava-pathelement location="/usr/local/lejos/lib/pc/3rdparty/bluecove.jar" />
    <rosjava-pathelement location="/home/jabrena/ros3/workspace/nxt_lejos_ros/NXTLoader/lib/yamlbeans-1.06.jar" />
</export>
```

My idea is to describe something similar to this one:

```
        <rosjava-pathelement location="./lib/pc/pccomm.jar" />
        <rosjava-pathelement location="./lib/bluecove-gpl.jar" />
        <rosjava-pathelement location="./lib/bluecove.jar" />
        <rosjava-pathelement location="./lib/yamlbeans-1.06.jar" />
```

Is it possible in a alternative way?

Juan Antonio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12666/how-to-set-relative-paths-in-the-node-%3Crosjava-pathelement%3E-included-in-a-manifest.xml-for-rosjava/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the path is relative, it will be evaluated as relative to the root of the package.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-01-23**:
If the path doesn't start with a "/" then it is relative to the root of the ROS package where the manifest.xml lives. For example, if you have /foo/bar/manifest.xml and a location "lib/baz.jar" it will resolve to /foo/bar/lib/baz.jar.

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-01-20**:
Hi Damon, I didn't understand your answer. Using the syntax: "" I didn't use relative paths. Does exist another way? Cheers